# Convert git repository file encoding

Tags: git, utf-8, character-encoding, cvs, cvs2svn

I have a large CVS repository containing files in `ISO-8859-1` and want to convert this to git.

Sure I can configure git to use `ISO-8859-1` for encoding, but I would like to have it in `utf8`.

Now with tools such as `iconv` or `recode` I can convert the encoding for the files in my working tree. I could commit this with a message like `converted encoding`.

My question now is, is there a possibility to convert the complete history? Either when converting from cvs to git or afterwards. My idea would be to write a script that reads each commit in the git repository and to convert it to `utf8` and to commit it in a new git repository.

Is this possible (I am unsure about the hash codes and how to walk through the commits, branches and tags). Or is there a tool that can handle something like this?

Comment: Yes, you can rewrite the history, but probably you shouldn't: You should never rewrite a repository, that you already pushed somewhere. My opinion is: `iconv` and a normal commit is the way to go.

Comment: Okay, thanks @KingCrunch. But since I newly create the git repository it is pushed to nowhere. And also I would accept to create a second repository with the ``utf8`` encoding based on the history of the first. Which is basically the same instead that I wouldn't modify the existing repo.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can do this with `git filter-branch`. The idea is that you have to change the encoding of the files in every commit, rewriting each commit as you go.

First, write a script that changes the encoding of every file in the repository. It could look like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

find . -type f -print | while read f; do
        mv -i "$f" "$f.recode.$$"
        iconv -f iso-8859-1 -t utf-8 < "$f.recode.$$" > "$f"
        rm -f "$f.recode.$$"
done
```

Then use `git filter-branch` to run this script over and over again, once per commit:

```
git filter-branch --tree-filter /tmp/recode-all-files HEAD
```

where `/tmp/recode-all-files` is the above script.

Right after the repository is freshly upgraded from CVS, you probably have just one branch in git with a linear history back to the beginning. If you have several branches, you may need to enhance the `git filter-branch` command to edit all the commits.

Comment: Great! Currently the command is running on a test git repository. Indeed I've a lot of branches, I just checked the documentation, do I just have to append ``--all`` to filter all branches?

Comment: For all others, ``git filter-branch --tree-filter /tmp/recode-all-files -- --all`` filters all branches.

Comment: I am trying to use your answer but I get a recode-all-files: command not found. I am using a mac, it appears to have iconv installed, I don't know if I have to set additional setting on that

Comment: In case you also used ISO-8859-1 characters in commit messages, you can convert those as well: `git filter-branch --msg-filter 'iconv -f iso-8859-1 -t utf-8' -- --all`