# Git: content of files not displaying non ASCII characters correctly

Tags: git

I have an Android project and I am using Git in Ubuntu.

I can commit my project just fine and read it correctly on github.com

But when I download it on Windows or Mac, I get some characters encoded differently (this for string in .java files for example, but not in strings.xml).

Researching I got to [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5854967/git-msysgit-accents-utf-8-the-definitive-answers), which led me to this page: https://github.com/kblees/git/wiki. But here they only talk about file names being encoded differently and commit messages. What I need to know is how to fix the **content of the files** that are being downloaded to Windows and Mac

I'm assuming is due to something I need to set on Git.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Hi Marima: have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11052199/convert-git-repository-file-encoding 

?

Comment: Hi Ahmed, I tried that solution but for some reason I get a "command not found" message for the script

Comment: iconv is missing on your system?

Comment: it says I have iconv in the Mac, I have never used it before though

Comment: Your editors need to be set to the same encoding. Git has nothing to do with this. You would have the same problem if you copied the file to a USB stick and then tranfered them to your Windows PC or your Mac.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Git does not touch the encoding of your files. The issues you are having are probably caused by your editors.

Comment: You are totally right, since I was working with eclipse in all the different OS I didn't think about this. I opened the files with a different text editor and the problem wasn't there. I ended up changing the encoding properties from the eclipse project and the problem was solved. Thanks!