# Cloudera Workbench string enoding problem

Tags: r, encoding, character-encoding, cloudera, cdsw

I am pulling changes from a git repo where my coworker pushed R codes from his local windows

```
word <- gsub("=gesellschaftmitbeschränkterhaftung=","",fixed = T,x = word)
```

The code contains weird letters, such as "German Umlaute", e.g., "ä" in the example above. On windows, this works fine. But when I open the same code on the Cloudera Data Science Workbench, it messed up the special character:

```
  word <- gsub("=gesellschaftmitbeschr�nkterhaftung=","",fixed = T,x = word)
```

I could manually replace it, but that is obviously a very painful solution and defeats the purpose of git. Is there any way to circumvent this issue? Find [here](https://github.com/JannicCutura/dyplr-vs-pandas/blob/master/example.R) the original R code, as pushed to Git from the windows machine containing all lines that cause issues.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://superuser.com/a/1347957) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39252721/3574579) help?