# Switching a Git repository from ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8 encoding for source code files

Tags: git, encoding, utf-8, iso-8859-1, reposurgeon

I'm going to convert a large Mercurial project to Git this weekend using [fast-export](https://github.com/frej/fast-export).  I've tested that several times, and the results are good.

We'd also like to turn our source code encoding (lots of German comments/string literals with Umlauts) from ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8 (all other non-java files in the repo should stay as-is), and the Git migration delivers us a chance to do it now since everybody needs to clone again anyway.  However, I don't find a good approach for it.

1. I've tried the `git filter-tree --tree-filter ...` approach from [this comment on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11052199/convert-git-repository-file-encoding#11053818).  However while this seems ideal, due to the size of the repository (about 200000 commits, 18000 code files) it would take much more time than just the weekend I have.  I've tried running it (in a heavily optimized version where the list of files is chunked and the sublists are converted in parallel (using [GNU parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/))) straight from a 64GB tmpfs volume on a linux VM with 72 cores, and still it would take several days...
2. Alternatively, I've tried the simple approach where I perform the conversion simply on any active branch individually and commit the changes.  However, the result is not satisfying because then I almost always get conflicts when merging or cherry-picking pre-conversion commits.
3. Now I'm running approach 1 again but not trying to rewrite the complete history of all branches (`--all` as `<rev-list>`) but just all commits reachable from the current active branches' and not reachable by some past commit which is (hopefully) a predecessor of all current branches (`branch-a branch-b branch-c --not old-tag-before-branch-a-b-c-forked-off` as `<rev-list>`).  It's still running but I fear that I can't really trust the results as this seems like a very bad idea.
4. We could just switch the encoding in the master branch with a normal commit as in approach 2, but again this would make cherry-picking fixes from/to master a disaster.  And it would introduce lots of encoding problems because developers would surely forget to change their IDE settings when switching between master and non-converted branches.

So right now, I somehow feel the best solution could be to just stick to ISO-8859-1.

Does anyone have an idea?  Someone mentioned that maybe [reposurgeon](http://www.catb.org/~esr/reposurgeon/) can do basically approach 1 using its `transcode` operation with a performance much better than `git filter-tree --tree-filter ...` but I have no clue how that works.

Comment: Note: if you have issue in commit messages encoding (in addition of code source file encoding), consider Git 2.23 (Q2 2019): see "[Migrate from CVS to Git without losing history](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56604301/6309)".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A tree filter in `git filter-branch` is inherently slow.  It works by extracting every commit into a full blown tree in a temporary directory, letting you change every file, and then figuring out what you changed and making the new commit from every file you left behind.

If you're exporting and importing through fast-export / fast-import, *that* would be the time to convert the data: you have the expanded data of the file in memory, but not in file-system form, before writing it to the export/import pipeline.  Moreover, `git fast-import` itself is a shell script so it's trivial to insert filtering there, and `hg-fast-export` is a Python program so it's trivial to insert filtering there as well.  The obvious place would be [here](https://github.com/frej/fast-export/blob/19aa906308568c3170a8742e039a5543a673fc4f/hg-fast-export.py#L133): just re-encode `d`.

Comment: Great! At that point I just need to check if it's actually a Java file because only those should be converted.

Comment: My Python foo is very very low.  So do you think this might do the trick (using chardet to detect the current encoding):

`d=ctx.filectx(file).data()
if (d != None) and (rx.match(file)): # rx is re.compile(".*\\.java"$)
    enc=chardet.detect(d)['encoding']
    if (enc != "ascii") and (enc != 'utf-8'):
        d=u''.join(d.decode(enc)).encode('utf8')`

Comment: I've never used `chardet`, but it seems like it would do the trick. You could simplify the file-name test, just check for `.endswith('.java')`. The last line would just be `d = d.decode('enc').encode('utf8')`.

Comment: Awesome!  Thanks a lot.  I've modified it a bit so that it can also gracefully handles files which have broken encoding and chardet guesses something very unlikely.  In those cases I simply convert to UTF-8 with `'replace'` as error handler which should insert the Unicode Replacement Character instead of producing garbage.  At least, that's easy to spot and fix afterwards.

Comment: Oops, I notice I put `enc` in quotes in my comment above (hazard of typing things into comments like this, I can't fix it now :-) ).

Comment: No problem, I still got it.

Comment: The conversion is still running but I guess it'll finish within the next 10 hours or so.  In the meantime, I've also run it on a copy of the same repository after nuking `.hg/` and initializing it anew, adding a handful of commits on top so that the history is not 200000 revisions but just 5.  The results of this test were absolutely fantastic, so I'll mark you solution as accepted answer. Thanks a ton!  :+1:

(I'll also contribute that back to fast-export, of course.  Maybe that could become a standard feature because I guess my task is not that uncommon.)

Comment: Our git and utf-8 migration using this approach was a great success. The results are extremely good. It ran for 56 hours, though, where it used to run for about 3-4 hours without the encoding part. 

Comment: Yikes, that's a lot of hours of transcoding :-)

Answer (score 2):

You might consider using `git filter-branch --index-filter`—as opposed to `--tree-filter` (which is the default). The idea is that with `--index-filter`, there's no checkout step (i.e. the worktree is not (re-)populated at all on each iteration).

So you might consider writing a filter for `git filter-branch --index-filter`
which would use `git ls-files`—something like this:

1. Call `git ls-files --cached --stage` and iterate over each entry.

   Consider only those which have the `100644`
   file mode—that is, are normal files.
2. For each entry run something like

   ```
   sha1=`git show ":0:$filename" \
       | iconv -f iso8859-1 -t utf-8 \
       | git hash-object -t blob -w --stdin`
   git update-index --cacheinfo "10644,$sha1,$filename" --info-only
   ```
3. Rinse, repeat.

An alternate approach I fathom would be to attack the problem from
a different angle: the format of streams generated by `git fast-export`
and consumed by `git fast-import` are plain text¹ (just pipe your exporter's
output to `less` or another pager and see for yourself).

You could write a filter using your favourite PL which would parse the
stream, re-encode any `data` chunks. The stream is organized in a way so that
no SHA-1 hashes are used so you may re-encode as you go.
The only apparent problem I fathom is that the `data` chunks bear no
information about which file they will represent in the resulting
commit (if any), so if you have non-text files in your history, you might
need to either resort to guessing based on the contents of each data blob
or make your processor more complicated by remembering the blobs it has seen
and deciding which of them to re-encoded after it saw the `commit` record
which assigns file names to (some of) those blobs.

---

¹ Documented in `git-fast-import(1)`—run `git help fast-import`.

Comment: That's also a good idea but as time presses, I use the approach to modify `hg-fast-export.py` to do the conversion there suggested by torek because my python foo is still better than my "shell and rather exotic git commands" foo. ;-)

But I'll come back to that next time!

WRT the streams idea: my problem is that sadly we don't have all files encoded in ISO-8859-1 but a wild mixture of ISO-8859-1, ISO-8859-15, UTF-8, cp1252, and simply broken.  So at least I have to do it on a file-based manner where I can first guess and then convert from the guessed encoding.

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same problem and the solution is based in @kostix answer of using as the basis the `--index-filter` option of `filter-branch`, but, with some additional improvements.

1. Use `git diff --name-only --staged` to detect the contents of the staging area
2. Iterate over this list and filter for:

   1. `git ls-files $filename`, i.e., it isn't a deleted file
   2. the result of `git show ":0:$filename" | file - --brief --mime-encoding` isn't `binary`, i.e., it is a text file, nor is already UTF-8 encoded
3. Use the detected mime encoding for each file
4. Use iconv to convert the the files
5. Detect the file mode with `git ls-files $filename --stage | cut -c 1-6`

This is the look of my bash function:

```
changeencoding() {
    for filename in `git diff --name-only --staged`; do
        # Only if file is present, i.e., filter deletions
        if [ `git ls-files $filename` ]; then
            local encoding=`git show ":0:$filename" | file - --brief --mime-encoding`
            if [ "$encoding" != "binary" -a  "$encoding" != "utf-8" ]; then
                local sha1=`git show ":0:$filename" \
                    | iconv --from-code=$encoding --to-code=utf-8 \
                    | git hash-object -t blob -w --stdin`
                local mode=`git ls-files $filename --stage | cut -c 1-6`
                git update-index --cacheinfo "$mode,$sha1,$filename" --info-only
            fi
        fi
    done
}
```